# How to create independent instances of shader node groups?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

I'm using Armzep's beautiful "Smartedges" shader node. It's working great!

I want to create separate instances of Smartedges for different materials used in the same Blender file with Smartedges having different settings for each material. The problem is that when I open and edit Smartedges in one material, it affects all other materials that also use Smartedges. How do I create separate and independent instances of Smartedges for use in different materials? Copying and pasting the Smartedges node group from one material to another doesn't fix the issue. Thanks. Blender 3.2.2, Windows 11.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Where it shows the number of users for the node group (in this case "4" on the attached screenshot), click on that number to make a "Single user copy." Works like a charm. :)

[image]